# generating two columns with randomly put 1,2 or 3 but different values for each row

Tags: r, random, duplicates, data-management

I am looking to assign 3 readers to a list of entries with ~1500 rows. Each row needs to be surveyed twice but not from the same person. My idea was to create two new columns in the data set with randomly put 1,2or3 for the respective readers. But the numbers need to be different for each column.

Anyone got an easy fix for that in R?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, please post the code. Post also sample data and expected output.

Comment: You could create a vector `("1_2", "2_3", "1_3")` and then `sample` from it 1500 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R function.

```
readers <- function(r, n){
  ex <- expand.grid(Reader.1 = seq_len(r), Reader.2 = seq_len(r))
  ex <- ex[ex[, 1] != ex[, 2], ]
  ex <- ex[sample(nrow(ex), n, TRUE), ]
  row.names(ex) <- NULL
  ex
}

set.seed(2020)
readers(3, n = 15)
#   Reader.1 Reader.2
#1         3        2
#2         3        2
#3         2        3
#4         2        1
#5         2        1
#6         3        2
#7         3        1
#8         2        3
#9         2        1
#10        1        3
#11        3        1
#12        3        1
#13        2        3
#14        1        3
#15        3        1
```

## Edit

Here is another solution.

```
readers2 <- function(r, n){
  df <- data.frame(Reader.1 = rep(seq_len(r), length.out = n))
  i1 <- seq(1, n, by = 3)
  i2 <- seq(2, n, by = 3)
  i3 <- seq(3, n, by = 3)
  df$Reader.2 <- NA_integer_
  df$Reader.2[i1] <- sample(2:3, length(i1), TRUE)
  df$Reader.2[i2] <- sample(c(1L,3L), length(i2), TRUE)
  df$Reader.2[i3] <- sample(1:2, length(i3), TRUE)
  df
}

set.seed(2020)
df <- readers2(3, 1500)
table(df$Reader.1)
#
#  1   2   3 
#500 500 500 

table(df$Reader.2)
#
#  1   2   3 
#505 479 516 

table(df)
#        Reader.2
#Reader.1   1   2   3
#       1   0 239 261
#       2 245   0 255
#       3 260 240   0
```

Answer (score 1):

if i have understood correctly:

You can use `sample()`

```
nums1 = c(1,2,3)
df$col1 = sample(nums1, length(df), replace = T)


nums2 = c(4,5,6)
df$col2 = sample(nums2, length(df), replace = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok to have fixed pairs in each row, you can use :

```
df$col1 <- rep(1:3, length.out = nrow(df))
df$col2 <- rep(c(2, 3, 1), length.out = nrow(df))
```

Here 1 and 2 will always encounter together, 2 and 3 and 3 and 1.

---

To get a truly random result where values don't overlap :

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
df$col1 <- sample(1:3, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$col2 <- sapply(df$col1, function(x) sample(setdiff(1:3, x), 1))
df

#    x col1 col2
#1   1    3    2
#2   2    3    2
#3   3    3    2
#4   4    2    1
#5   5    3    2
#6   6    2    1
#7   7    2    3
#8   8    2    1
#9   9    3    1
#10 10    1    2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(arrangements)
library(tidyverse)

x <- permutations(3, 2, nsample=1500)
d <- tibble(ID=1:1500, Reader1=x[,1], Reader2=x[,2])
d
# A tibble: 1,500 x 3
      ID Reader1 Reader2
   <int>   <int>   <int>
 1     1       3       2
 2     2       2       1
 3     3       3       2
 4     4       2       3
 5     5       3       1
 6     6       1       2
 7     7       2       3
 8     8       1       2
 9     9       3       2
10    10       2       1
# … with 1,490 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `base R` solution:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:1500))
vec <- c(1,2,3)
df$col1 <- rep(1:3, length.out = nrow(df))
df$col2[df$col1 == 1] <- rep(2:3)
df$col2[df$col1 == 2] <- rep(1,3)
df$col2[df$col1 == 3] <- rep(1:2)
```

This gives an even distribution for `col1` and not so much for `col2`:

```
> table(df$col1)

  1   2   3 
500 500 500 

> table(df$col2)

  1   2   3 
750 500 250
```